# Does anyone here know how to apply for MFi product plan id to LEGO?

Tags: ev3

Does anyone here have an idea as to how to apply to LEGO to get MFi product plan id? Or how do I get to their MFi product plan form?

Answer (score 2):

MFi (Made For iPod/iPhone/iPad) is a program from Apple, not LEGO. You can apply on Apple's website: https://developer.apple.com/programs/mfi/.

Comment: One needs to apply to Apple if one is manufacturing an MFi accessory. But if one is writing an ios app that communicates with such an accessory, for publishing that app on App store, one needs permission from the Manufacturer of that Accessory which in my case happens to be Lego.

Comment: In that case, I would suggest updating your question to make it more clear what you are asking. Do you have a link from Apple about this requirement? I have seen people using EV3 with iOS in their own apps, but I have never heard of anyone who tried to submit it to the App store, so I am not familiar with that process.